# Apply single transformation to multiple divs

Tags: css

Is it it possible to apply one single 3D transformation to multiple DIVS at once?
I tried to apply translate3d to container DIV that contains several child DIVs and I thought that children would be transformed too. One particularity here is that each child DIV already has its own transformation. So I want those children transformation matrices to be multiplied by single container transformation matrix. Is my approach correct?

Comment: I don't think it would be wrong, that's what css is for, apply same styles to multiple div's..

Comment: If I understand you correctly then yes, applying a transformation to a parent will make the children transform as well. Example: http://exscale.se/__files/uploads/jquery-3d-circle.htm

Comment: Thanks, people. If you had written this as an answer, I would've marked it as correct. I even found example already: http://www.clicktorelease.com/tutorials/css3dclouds/#creating_a_world_and_a_camera